# How to set user defined Keyboard layout in chromebox kiosk app

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk-mode, chromebox

is there a way to let the user set the keyboard layout on chrome app which is running on chrome box in kiosk mode?

I couldn't find an chrome runtime API for this!